# Flow doesn't infer type refinement when using imported function

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a React component that is typed using Flow:

```
import { isFunction } from './utils';

type Props = {
  ...
  onRemove?: Function,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    // ...
  }

  _handleRemove = () => {
    if (isFunction(this.props.onRemove)) {
      this.props.onRemove();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `isFunction` util:

```
export function isFunction(value: any): boolean %checks {
  return typeof value === 'function';
}
```

Flow throws the following error when checking my code:

```
Cannot call onRemove because undefined [1] is not a function.
```

Either omitting the util function and simply using `typeof this.props.onRemove === 'function'` or moving the function definition into the component file fixed the error, but I'd obviously like to be able to use the util function throughout my codebase.

Am I doing something wrong or does Flow have problems when using imports? If the latter, is there a known workaround?

Comment: There's an issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3635

Comment: As a side note: 1. Do not use `Function` type. It's an alias for `any`. 2. In your specific case it's enough to write just `if (this.props.onRemove)`, you don't need a function

Comment: Thanks @AlexSavin! Wow, 2017, doesn't seem like it'll be fixed any time soon...

Comment: I pasted your snippets into two separate files in a brand new Flow root, made a couple of tweaks to fix unrelated errors (import react, remove the `...`, return something from the render function). I was unable to reproduce this on Flow v0.110.1. Could you try this on the latest version, and if you can still reproduce, include more details?